# K1 form versus 1099 form: Is the K1 required to prepare my taxes?

Tags: united-states, income-tax, form-1099

I did some commodity, commodity options (like SLV, GLD), ETF and ETN trading last year. I lost my K1 forms when I moved to a different state.

My broker has provided me 1099 forms which also state profits and losses.

Do I need the K1 forms to prepare my taxes? (It is due October 15, due to late filing.)

If needed, how can I get the K1 forms? My broker says he is not responsible.

Answer (score 1):

You need the K-1 forms, you can get them directly from the partnerships (they have their own web sites: [SLV](http://us.ishares.com/product_info/fund/overview/SLV.htm), [GLD](https://www.spdrs.com/product/fund.seam?ticker=GLD)). Broker doesn't have these forms and doesn't have this information, broker can only tell you the information pertaining the purchase and the sale of the interests.